# How to perform a calculation function to calculate the difference?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

In my application I have a table which looks like this below for example:

```
Question No.    Question                 Answer     Marks per Answer    Total Marks
1               Here are 2 answers       B          (text input)            5
                                         D          (text input)
2               Here is a single answer  True       (text input)            5
```

In the table above I have a text input which belongs to each answer. Now each question has its own amount of total marks. What I want to do is that if the user enters in a number in the text input, it should do a calculation on the difference between the number entered in the text input and the number under the "Total Marks" column. So if you look at the example below:

```
 Question No.   Question                 Answer     Marks per Answer    Total Marks
 1              Here are 2 answers       B          (text input) = 2        2
                                         D          (text input) = 1
 2              Here is a single answer  True       (text input) = 5        0
```

As you can see in the table above, the text inputs for the answers in question 1 equals 3 altogether. So 5 (from total marks for question 1) minus 3 = 2 (Total marks now equals 2)

For question 2, the text input for the answer in question 2  equals 5, so 5 (from total marks for question 2) minus 5 = 0 (Total marks now equals 0).

**MY QUESTIONS:**

1. How and what is the best method to use in order to perform these calculations?

2.What I also want is that if a question only contains a single answer (like question 2 in the above example only has one answer), then I want the text input to become readonly and the text input should display the same number as the total marks as that it has to equal the same marks anyway, so it would look like this below:

```
Question No.   Question                  Answer     Marks per Answer             Total Marks
 2              Here is a single answer  True       (text input(readonly)) = 5        0
```

Here is a jsfiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AeT6E/4/) so you know what the HTML code looks like. In the jsffidle what I have done is that in the textboxes I inserted the values in them, but I left the "Total marks" for questions to "5" when really they should both make "0" if you calculate the difference between the total marks and the numbers entered in the text inputs. Also question 2's text input is readonly, this is because it is just a single answer to this question

Below is the html code which is in the jsfiddle:

```
<table border='1' id='markstbl'>
<tr>
<th class='questionth'>Question No.</th>
<th class='questionth'>Question</th>
<th class='answerth'>Answer</th>
<th class='answermarksth'>Marks per Answer</th>
<th class='noofmarksth'>Total Marks</th>
</tr>
<tr class="questiontd">
<td class="questionnumtd" rowspan="2">1</td>
<td class="questioncontenttd" rowspan="2">Here are 2 Answers Question</td>
<td class="answertd">B</td>
<td class="answermarkstd"><input class="individualMarks" name="answerMarks[]" id="individualtext" type="text" value="3" /></td>
<td class="noofmarkstd" rowspan="2">5</td>
</tr>
<tr class="questiontd">
<td class="answertd">D</td>
<td class="answermarkstd"><input class="individualMarks" name="answerMarks[]" id="individualtext" type="text" value="2" /></td>
</tr>
<tr class="questiontd">
<td class="questionnumtd" rowspan="2">2</td>
<td class="questioncontenttd" rowspan="2">Here is single Answer Question</td>
<td class="answertd">True</td>
<td class="answermarkstd"><input class="individualMarks" name="answerMarks[]" id="individualtext" type="text" value="5" readonly="readonly"/></td>
<td class="noofmarkstd" rowspan="2">5</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Let me just say that there are can be numerous questions and numerous answers, please don't just provide an answer that fits for only this example. It needs to work if there are numerous answers in a question.

Comment: why are you posting server code and not live html? You could make this a lot easier to follow with html and a demo in jsfiddle.net that outlines the roww rules

Comment: @charlietfl When you say you want to see live html, do you mean the view page source? I am more than happy creating a jsfiddle demo to show what table could look like. Give me 10 mins to make the demo in jsfiddle

Comment: yes..replace all the php...it doesn't fit in context of a javascript calculation issue.

Comment: @charlietfl Ok here is the jsfiddle demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AeT6E/4/) I will replace the php code to show just the html equivalent. In the textboxes I inserted the values in them, but I left the "Total marks" for questions to "5" when really they should both make "0" if you calculate the difference between the total marks and the numbers entered in the text inputs

Comment: @charlietfl Also question 2's text input is readonly, this is because it is just a single answer to this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that is the basic framework for doing the calcs. You will need to adjust if you need any validation rules

```
$('tr').each(function() {
    var $input = $(this).find('input');
    var $row = $(this);
    var is_multiple = !$input.prop('readonly');
    var rowClass = is_multiple ? 'multiple' : 'single';
    if (is_multiple) {
        var is_first = $row.find('td').length == 5;
        rowClass += is_first ? ' first' : ' second';
    } else {
        /* readonly just needs marks changed once on page load */
        $row.find('.noofmarkstd').text(5 - $input.val());
    }
    $input.addClass(rowClass);
});

$('input.multiple').keyup(function() {
    var $input = $(this);
    var is_first = $input.is('.first');
    var $row = $input.closest('tr');
    var $otherRow = $row[is_first ? 'next' : 'prev']();
    var $marks = is_first ? $row.find('.noofmarkstd') : $otherRow.find('.noofmarkstd');

    var calcs = 5 - ($input.val() || 0) - ( $otherRow.find('input.multiple').val() || 0);
    $marks.text(calcs);    
});

/* if need calcs for multiples generated on pageload trigger a change on the first in set*/
 $('input.first').change();
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/jTXy5/1/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I just have one question, I have updated your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jTXy5/3/). Obviously your fiddle works if there is 2 answers. But in the updated fiddle I have added an extra answer so that question 1 has 3 answers. Now text inputs for 1st and 2nd answers work when it comes to calculation but not 3rd text input. Each question can have a number of answers, there could be 1, 2, 3 or even 10 answers per question. So what needs to be changed in order for calculation to work for numerous text inputs?

Comment: ok...  original post implied 1 or 2. Assume your php can tell how many are in a group? If so will help a lot adding extra markup to be able to "group" all the inputs and totals box. Then can loop over the whole "group" with simple js code. If you used a `data-` html5 attribute on all the inputs with somehting like `question_` plus number so all in that group have same data value.

Comment: demo with adjusted markup. **Note** no `rowspan=2` cells in single `readonly` questions and added some data attributes in others. Code is actually simpler than original with these adjustments.  http://jsfiddle.net/JWTQk/1/

Answer (score 0):

If the values you are dealing with a numbers represented by strings, and you are doing simple mathematic operations like addition, division, etc., then you only need to be careful of addition.

An expression with the "+" operator where one value is a string will cause it to be treated as concatenating a string rather than adding numbers. So you can either convert everything to a number (say using parseInt, parseFloat or Number called as a function), or you can just deal with it where you have addition.

e.g. given string values:

```
var a = '5';
var b = '6;
```

In all of the following, `a` and `b` are converted to numbers because of the use of a mathematic operator:

```
 a * b // 30 

 a - b // -1 

 a / b // 0.833333...
```

but

```
 a + b // 56
```

because if one of the operands is a string, all the others are converted to strings and "+" is used for concatenation.

So for addition you can do:

```
 +a + +b // 11
```

as "+" in a place where addition or concatenation can't occur causes it to be treated as the unary operator, so it converts a and b to numbers. So the "+" in the middle is then treated as addition since it's dealing with numbers.

Any scheme that causes the value of a and b to be a number before the "+" is applied will mean it's treated as addition, e.g.:

```
parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);

Number(a) + Number(b);

a*1 + b*1  // since multiplication is done before addition
```

and so on. Just use whatever seems best and will be clearest to those that try to maintain your code (which might be you).

Comment: I think it will be better if I use a javascript function and simply use the javascript function to simply determine what is entered in the text input and minus the difference with the total mark. That way if the user enters in a number in the text input and clicks away, it does the calculation and shows the new value straight away for total marks. I appreciate your effort tho :) but think I need to do it javascript method

Comment: Also there could be numerous answers. A question can have 1,2 3, or 10 answers. There is no fixed values on the number of answers so no fixed numbers of text inputs (as each text input belongs to answer within a question)